# Правильно ли расставлены знаки препинания перед союзами "и"?

Tags: запятые, союзы

Если ситуация выйдет из под контроля, позвоните в службу технической поддержки, и опытный мастер решит проблему.

Является ли второстепенная часть с союзом "если" общей для последующих частей сложного предложения, начинающихся с "позвоните", "и опытный"?
Думаю, структура предложения такова: сложноподчиненное предложение (если...то) + независимое. Следовательно, запятые перед союзами "и" нужны. Да?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Здесь возможны **оба варианта:**

(1) ***Если ситуация выйдет из под контроля**, позвоните в службу технической поддержки, **и** опытный мастер решит проблему.*

Придаточное относится **только** ко второму простому предложению  в составе **сложного,** запятая перед союзом ***И*** ставится.

(2) ***Если ситуация выйдет из под контроля,** позвоните в службу технической поддержки **и** опытный мастер решит проблему.*

Здесь **общее** придаточное (относится к обоим простым предложениям); при наличии союза ***И*** запятая **не ставится.**

**2. Что выбрать?** Я бы выбрала **второй вариант**. В этом случае фирма гарантирует **быстрое** решение проблемы)  А если поставить запятую, то предложение выглядит **неопределенно** во временном плане.